# How to continuously run shadow effect through texts in android text view?

Tags: java, android, textview

[image]

How to run shadow effect through the texts in android text view. Pls refer the above image. white color shadow runs from the starting letter 'S' to end letter 's' of text "Slide for options". Current white shadow position 'opt' in "options". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

TextView Slide effect example, like iPhone style "Slide to unlock"

try this. https://github.com/FrankNT/TextViewSlideEffect

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setShadowLayer (float radius, float dx, float dy, int color)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setShadowLayer%28float,%20float,%20float,%20int%29)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.But I want to run the shadow effect continuously through texts in textview just like marquee text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html). (It allows setting different looks to different parts of a string)

Comment: How to continuously run the spannableString.